# Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-1.1

We were provided a set of schemas from a vendor, (we have alerted them to the error as well).
When I try to generate the Java classes using xjc, it fails with the error below

```
C:\Users\...>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\xjc.exe" -d output ICSv1.01.xsd
```

parsing a schema...

> [ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'ICSBatchV01' is
>   invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   line 77 of file:/C:/Users/.../ICSv1.01.xsd
>
> [ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'ICSDocBody' is
>   invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
>   line 215 of file:/C:/Users/.../ICSv1.01.xsd
>
> Failed to parse a schema.

I also tried java 8, and the latest and greatest jaxb (outside of java dist)

However, it does work with Altova's xmlspy software, but trying to avoid vendor lock-in/non standard stuff.
I did some searching here and the web (mostly here)

Here is the header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2015 rel. 4 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)  -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xmlns:msg01="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg01.001" xmlns:msg02="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg02.001" xmlns:msg03="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg03.001" xmlns:msg04="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg04.001" xmlns:msg05="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg05.001" xmlns:msg06="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg06.001" xmlns:msg07="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg07.001" xmlns:msg08="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg08.001" xmlns:msg09="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg09.001" xmlns:msg11="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg11.001" xmlns:msg12="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg12.001" xmlns:msg13="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg13.001" xmlns:msg14="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msg14.001" xmlns:msq01="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msq01.001" xmlns:msq02="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msq02.001" xmlns:msq03="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msq03.001" xmlns:msq04="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msq04.001" xmlns:msq05="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msq05.001" xmlns:msf01="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msf01.001" xmlns:msf02="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msf02.001" xmlns:msf03="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msf03.001" xmlns:msf04="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msf04.001" xmlns:mss01="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.mss01.001" xmlns:mss02="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.mss02.001" xmlns:mss03="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.mss03.001" xmlns:mss04="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.mss04.001" xmlns:msp01="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msp01.001" xmlns:msp02="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msp02.001" xmlns:msp03="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msp03.001" xmlns:msp04="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.msp04.001" xmlns:doc="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.doc.001" xmlns="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.doc.001" targetNamespace="urn:cccc:tech:xsd:ics.doc.001" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
```

Here is the relevant snippet.
Starting at line 44 and ending at line 77 (where the xjc convert reported the first error)

```
    <xs:complexType name="ICSBatchV01">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="DocHdr" type="ICSDocumentHeader"/>
        <xs:element name="DocBody" type="ICSDocBody"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG01' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg01:MSG01PmtSubm) = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or 
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG02' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg02:MSG02PmtSubmAckNak) = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG03' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg03:MSG03TSetRejection)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG04' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg04:MSG04LocalBankHoliday)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG05' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg05:MSG05BeneficiaryFraudNotn)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG06' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg06:MSG06PmtRequest)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG07' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg07:MSG07PmtResponse)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG08' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg08:MSG08PmtResponseAckNak)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG09' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg09:MSG09PmtResponseItemRejection)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG11' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg11:MSG11SettlementPreventedNotn)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG12' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg12:MSG12DefaultPmtResponseNotn)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG13' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg13:MSG13PmtNotn)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSG14' and (count(doc:DocBody/msg14:MSG14PmtFrdStsUp)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSQ01' and (count(doc:DocBody/msq01:MSQ01QueryMessage)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSQ02' and (count(doc:DocBody/msq02:MSQ02QuerySubmAckNak)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSQ03' and (count(doc:DocBody/msq03:MSQ03QueryRejection)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSQ04' and (count(doc:DocBody/msq04:MSQ04QueryNotn)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSQ05' and (count(doc:DocBody/msq05:MSQ05QuerySettlementPrevented)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSF01' and (count(doc:DocBody/msf01:MSF01FrdSetUnset)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSF02' and (count(doc:DocBody/msf02:MSF02FraudItemSubmAckNak)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSF03' and (count(doc:DocBody/msf03:MSF03FraudItemRejection)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSF04' and (count(doc:DocBody/msf04:MSF04FrdSetUnsetNotn)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSS01' and (count(doc:DocBody/mss01:MSS01StopChq)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSS02' and (count(doc:DocBody/mss02:MSS02StopChqAckNak)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSS03' and (count(doc:DocBody/mss03:MSS03StopChqRejection)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSS04' and (count(doc:DocBody/mss04:MSS04StopChq )  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSP01' and (count(doc:DocBody/msp01:MSP01PrevPd)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSP02' and (count(doc:DocBody/msp02:MSP02PrevPdAckNak)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSP03' and (count(doc:DocBody/msp03:MSP03PrevPdRejection)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs))) or
    (doc:DocHdr/doc:DocTyp='MSP04' and (count(doc:DocBody/msp04:MSP04PrevPd)  = xs:integer(doc:DocHdr/doc:NbOfTxs)))
    ">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>MIG 10.1 NbOfTxs (MWR030): count of messages in document</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation>MIG 10.1 DocTyp: code identifying the document content</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:assert>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSD 1.1 is required for `xs:assert`, but JAXB only supports XSD 1.0, not XSD 1.1.  None of the requests to add support for XSD 1.1 have be addressed (references: [here](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/1176) and [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8197490)).

### What to do:

- Contribute support yourself, or hope that someone else does (unlikely).
- In the meantime, analyse the XSDs for 1.1 dependencies.  If mild,
  such as only use of `xs:assert`, write a simple XSLT transformation
  to strip `xs:assert` validations so that you can still generate
  classes.  (See XSLT below.)  Optionally, as needed, implement the `xs:assert` checks
  in Java code manually.

**XSLT to strip `xs:assert`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xs:assert"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you kjhughes, I manually removed the xs:asserts and got some other errors (which I unfortunately dont have handy)

Comment: I found the scratchpad of the errors after manually removing the asserts After removing all asserts
C:\perforce\COMMON\ICSv1.01>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\xjc.exe
" -d src/main/java -p com.netdeposit.ics src/main/resources/ICSv1.01.xsd
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve thi
s conflict.
  line 177 of file:/C:/perforce/COMMON/ICSv1.01/src/main/resources/ICSv1.01.xsd

[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 178 of file:/C:/perforce/COMMON/ICSv1.01/src/main/resources/ICSv1.01.xsd

Comment: @unsavorycoder: You're welcome.  If these new errors are still a problem, please post a new question; you might want to link to it here.

Comment: @kjhughes The given resource links doesnt work. Is  xsd 1.1 is supported by JAXB?

Comment: @SangamBelose: I've updated the answer since those links have rotted.  Unfortunately, there still is not support for XSD 1.1 in JAXB, and at this point such support would appear to be unlikely.