# Validation of xml based on certain constrains

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I am new to writing the validation of xml, can anyone please help in below query.
I want to fail the XSD validation if each element of the XML has the same value i.e. 'N'. If it has some other combination it should get pass the validation.

See the below XML and XSD :

```
<noticeOfEligibility>
    <displayHCCTable>N</displayHCCTable>
    <displaySNAPTable>N</displaySNAPTable>
    <displayTANFTable>N</displayTANFTable>
    <displayCCAPTable>N</displayCCAPTable>
    <displayLIHEAPTable>N</displayLIHEAPTable>
    <displayLIHEAPShareTable>N</displayLIHEAPShareTable>        
</noticeOfEligibility>
```

XSD:

```
 <xs:complexType name="noticeOfEligibility">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="displayHCCTable" type="xs:string" />               
        <xs:element name="displaySNAPTable" type="xs:string" />               
        <xs:element name="displayTANFTable" type="xs:string" />                
        <xs:element name="displayCCAPTable" type="xs:string" />                
        <xs:element name="displayLIHEAPTable" type="xs:string" />               
        <xs:element name="displayLIHEAPShareTable" type="xs:string" />                
        <xs:element name="displayEmgyLIHEAPTable" type="xs:string" />                
        <xs:element name="displayLIHEAPVendorTable" type="xs:string" />               
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `xs:assert` validator (I added a few elements but you get the idea)

`<xs:complexType name="noticeOfEligibility">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="displayHCCTable" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="displaySNAPTable" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="displayTANFTable" type="xs:string" />
        <!-- more elements here -->
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="displayHCCTable != 'N' and displaySNAPTable != 'N' and displayTANFTable != 'N'"/>
</xs:complexType>`

Works for XSD 1.1.

Comment: Hi Luis,

I am getting below error when I placed assert statement in xsd.



S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'sequence' Must Match (annotation?, (element | Group | Choice | Sequence | Any)*). A Problem Was Found Starting At: Assert.


Do I need to add any other line I tried along with restriction as well.

Comment: The xs:assert goes outside the sequence element. See examples [here](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html).

Comment: I am using the same way as below, still getting the issue:

 <xs:element name="displayLIHEAPVendorTable" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="displayHCCTable != 'N' and displaySNAPTable != 'N' and displayTANFTable != 'N'" />
        </xs:complexType>

Error:

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_noticeOfEligibility' is invalid. Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518325/element-assert-is-invalid-misplaced-or-occurs-too-often